# "Tricks" to filling a "rolling" time-series array absent brute-force pushback of all values each iteration

Tags: c++, arrays

My applications is financial, in C++, Visual Studio 2003.

I'm trying to maintain an array of the last (x) values for an observation, and as each new value arrives I have a loop first push all of the other values back then add the new value in the front.

It's computationally intensive, and I've been trying to be clever and come up with some way around this. I've probably either stated an oxymoronic problem or reached the limit of my intellect, or both.

Here's an idea I have:

Suppose it's 60 seconds of data, and new data arrive each second.  Suppose we have an integer between 0 and 59, that will serve to index an element of the array. Suppose each second, when the data arrives, we first iterate the integer then overwrite the element of the array at that index with the new data. Then, suppose in our calculations, we refer to the same integer as the base, work backwards to zero, then to 59 then back down again. The formulas in the math would be a bit more tedious to write. But my application does a lot of these pushback/fills of arrays, each second for several data points, and each array having 3600 elements per data series (one hour of seconds).

Does the board think this is a good idea? Or am I being silly here?

Comment: "Dose C++ support modulo?" -- I think it may be a little early for you to a) be on Stack Overflow (there are millions of better, cheaper resources for you that don't require human attention) and b) to apply C++ to finance (stop gambling away my pensions).

Comment: You could use boost::circular buffer: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html

Comment: Why use an array when you can use a vector? Remove the last item, and add a new one at the front.

Comment: `C++, Visual Studio 2003` Greetings time traveller!

Comment: @user657267: From my Turbo C++ vantage point, this is alien future scifi tech! What with its shiny templates and all that.

Comment: @KerrekSB My condolences.

Comment: Jopa, thanks, that looks perfect, like what I saw in my head.

Comment: Kerrek, I play with my own money, and I regret adding that in stream-of-consciousness.

Comment: @user657267: Good one. It was free of charge. I haven't made enough off of Kerrek's pension to afford the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is nothing more than a circular buffer.
There's an implementation in Boost, and probably in other
libraries as well, and a good algorithm description on the
Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

And yes, it's a good solution for the problem you describe.

Comment: Implemented (coded myself- didn't use library). Thanks for the confirmation it was a good route to take. Seems to have helped but there is so much going on it's hard to benchmark. it saves "moving" 3600 x 18 x 2 doubles every second. You are very polite and I really appreciate the help. Despite the downrates, I could not find anything on Google before I came in here- I did not know how to state the keywords properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use modulo as you suggested (hint: `x % y` is the syntax for "x" modulo "y"), or you could maintain two buffers where you essentially swap which one is the current data to be read and which buffer is the stale data that is to be overwritten. For copying large quantities of plain-old-data (POD) data, you should take a look at [memcpy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/memcpy.html). Of course, in quantitative trading, people will do all sorts of things to get a speed edge, including custom hardware that allows one to bypass several layers of copying.

Comment: I would expect that `std::copy` would be faster than `std::memcpy`, regardless of the type of data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are talking about arrays? They don't have a "push" operation - it sounds more like an std::vector.

Anyway, here is the solution for what I think that you want:

If I understood it right, you want a collection of 3600 elements and each second the last element drops off and a new element is added.

So you should use a linked list queue for that task. Operations are performed in O(1).

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasn't formally referring to a push, rather a loop to set the value at index i to be that at index i + 1.

Comment: Since his problem is performance, he definitely doesn't want an `std::list`  For 3600 elements of a simple, inserting one at the front and removing the last will be faster with an `std::vector`.

Comment: @JamesKanze I said a linked list queue - not a std::list. If you want performance, you kick out the whole STL nonsense anyway and write your own queue data structure.

Comment: @UniversE Either way: link lists are extremely expensive on modern architectures.